# Deploy api with basic auth in Wso2 apim

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb, wso2-api-manager, wso2-identity-server, wso2-enterprise-integrator

I have python api that used basic auth for successfull response.
Here I'm passing username and password of my application

Now I am looking for deploy this api in Wso2 apim with basic auth policy.
Here passing username and password wso2 apim

How I can manage this scenario in Wso2.

Comment: I'm not sure what are you trying to do.. wso2apim is an api manager (and gateway) on its own, not that one can simply deploy any python module in it.. do you want to expose the same api (set of services)? Do you have the api definition (swagger file)? Or you just want to pass the Authorization header?

Comment: Suppose I have python api A where I need to pass Autherization header. This api A I need to deploy in Wso2 for wso2 api access I am using basic auth instead of bearer token

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this is by [disabling security](https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/design/api-security/api-authentication/disable-security/) at the APIM layer and letting your Python service validate the Basic Auth header. You can pass the Authorization header and WSO2 will pass it through to your Python API where the actual validation happens.

If you want to do Basic Auth header validation in APIM you can connect APIM to a userstore and [enable Basic Auth](https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/design/api-security/api-authentication/secure-apis-using-basic-authentication/) for the API. If you want to pass the same header to the backend as well you can [enable this](https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/reference/faq/#how-can-i-add-authentication-headers-to-messages-going-out-of-the-api-gateway-to-the-backend) config.